# jQuery data with dynamically created elements and event handlers

Tags: jquery, events, dataset

I would like to know why updating data of dynamically created element affects other element's data created before.

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/bmq3sk9c/

```
var createComment = function(data) {
    var post = $("<div/>").addClass("com").html("lorem "+Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)).data("extra", data);
    var btn = $("<a/>", {href:"",class:"sbm"}).text("submit");
    post.append(btn);
    post.on("submit", submitComment);

    post.appendTo("body");
};
var submitComment = function(e){
    //ajax here
    $(this).data("extra").time = new Date().getTime();//why this affects data of previously created comments
    $(this).find(".sbm").remove();
    test();
};
var test = function(){
    $("body").find(".com").each(function(){
      console.log($(this).data("extra")); 
    });
}
var d = {
    param: "test",
    a: "another"
};

$(".crea").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    createComment(d);
});
$("body").on("click", ".sbm", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".com").trigger("submit");
});
```

I'm guessing what the problem is... But I would like to know how can I make a workaround thanks a lot!

Comment: Please explain if you already have an idea as to what the problem is...

Comment: i create every new post dynamically creating element and attaching to it all the event handlers and some custom data. (var post).post has submit method on it which sends some hypo data to server and gets a timestamp  which i should put in a data of this particular post, but when i am having second post create the same way and i am submitting it the data changes not only to current but for previous one. i know i can handle this problem by using hardcoded data like .attr("data-set", "val") this way it works but i cant get it why data not

Comment: seems like .data sticks to every post created not $(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is data sharing occurred because of object usage. You should pass to *.data()* a deep copy of the object to prevent it:

```
var createComment = function(data) {
  var post = $("<div/>").addClass("com").html("lorem "+Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1))
  post.data("extra", $.extend({}, data));
  /* ... */
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot i guess that is because objects are passed by ref. what a shame for me))) basic things in js...Thanks again)